# Combinatorics and Inversion Sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Determine the inversion sequence of the following permutation of $ \{ 1,\ 2, \cdots , 8 \}$.

$$ 83476215 $$

I just don't understand how that is converted into a series of numbers 0, 1, and 2 and what that means.

For example The inversion sequence of the permutation $ 31524 $ is $ 1,\ 2,\ 0,\ 1,\ 0  $

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Other sources would not agree with that inversion sequence for 31524, and would define it to be the same as the inversion vector of the permutation.

Comment: Probably the inversion sequence for a permutation $\sigma$ here is $n \mapsto \#\{k \mid k>n \textrm{ and } \sigma(k) < \sigma(n)\}$.  At least that matches the example.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that $\pi=p_1p_2\ldots p_n$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Its inversion sequence (or inversion vector) is the $n$-tuple $\langle i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n\rangle$, where $i_k$ is the number of integers larger than $k$ that precede $k$ in $\pi$. (In what follows I’ll omit the brackets and commas from the inversion sequence.)

Suppose that $\pi=35712846$. The $1$ is preceded by $3$ larger numbers, $3$, $5$, and $7$, so $i_1=3$. The $2$ is also preceded by $3$ larger numbers, so $i_2=3$ as well. The $3$ is not preceded by any larger numbers, so $i_3=0$. The $4$ is preceded by the $3$ larger numbers $5$, $7$, and $8$, so $i_4=3$. The $5$ is not preceded by any larger integers, so $i_5=0$. The $6$ is preceded by both $7$ and $8$, so $i_6=2$. The $8$ does not precede the $7$, so $i_7=0$, and clearly $i_8=0$. Thus, the inversion sequence of $\pi$ is $33030200$. Now see if you can find the inversion sequence of $83476215$; I’ve left it spoiler-protected below.

> $65113210$

Comment: I got - 01112563. Is inversion table different from inversion sequence. I am following Sedgewick, Chap 7.1

Comment: @500_error: An inversion table is the same thing as an inversion sequence, at least in every source that I’ve seen, and what you have there isn’t the inversion table for $83476215$. The first entry should be the number of larger numbers preceding the $1$, not the number of larger numbers preceding the first entry ($8$). The second entry should be the number of larger entries preceding the $2$, not the number of larger numbers preceding the second entry ($3$). However, I’m not familiar with Sedgewick, so it’s possible that the term is defined differently there.